# Need for SEO friendly url for my Existing opencart e-commerce website

Tags: php, opencart

I have an opencart e-commerce website. For this website I have used VQMOD models and Custom plugins. Once I click the home menu of my website the following URL `Domainname/?route=common/home` is obtained, but I need the above URL to be an SEO friendly URL as `Domainname/home`.

I just tried to fix SEO friendly URL opencart models in my website, but it's not working, kindly suggest how to resolve this issue.

Comment: "I just tried" where? What does your code look like?

Comment: Would this rewrite rule work? `RewriteRule ^(.+)$  index.php?route=common/$1 [N]`

Answer (score 0):

You can see below Some Tutorials for SEO URL: (Hope, helpfully for you.)

http://cartadvisor.com/blog/2013/09/12/how-to-turn-on-seo-friendly-urls-in-opencart/
http://iam.chynhuei.com/2013/10/26/opencart-how-to-enable-seo-friendly-urls-and-editing-htaccess/
https://support.terranetwork.net/web/knowledgebase/184/Enabling-SEO-URLs-for-OpenCart.html